# "ic_launcher cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: java, android, icons

I was following a tutorial of Android and 
When I was done everything, I got a problem in this code:

```
getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

And I got the message

```
**"ic_launcher cannot be resolved or is not a field"**
```

What's more, my icon doesn't appear in tablet emulator, 
but starts automatic. 
What's going on?

Comment: do you have ic_launcher in your drawable folder??

Comment: +1 Raghunandan i guess you are having icon.png in your drawable.

Comment: which IDE are you using? this would narrow the odds how the standard-icon is named :)

Answer (score 12):

**replace "mipmap" with "drawable"**

I had the same problem while following a tutorial and i found out that my AndroidManifest.xml file had the following code :-

`android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher`

so I changed R.drawable to R.mipmap it solved the problem . Wherever I found out drawable I replaced it with mipmap. Good to check for mipmap with android studio 1.1.
for more info :-https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/02/14/goodbye-launcher-drawables-hello-mipmaps/

Answer (score 3):

Check top line of your activity if have an import of

`import android.R`

delete it and clean your app.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I solved the problem:

In my program there had been android.R import so it was giving error for R.drawable.ic_launcher  ....removing android.R import worked for me..!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should check if under the `dir gen` there's a file called `R.java`. If so open it and check if there's an attribute called `icon`.

It could be that you moved your project or copied something from other projects. In any case you can remove the file manually under `gen` and let Eclipse recreate them. If not, you can go under `Projects` and then `Clean` choosing your project. It should work.

**OR**

I just thought I would add a quick additional answer to this topic. I am very new to Android development and had found that one of my classes was not compiling as it could not find any of my drawable attributes. In the end I tracked the problem down to the fact that the class was importing `android.R` (automatically added to the imports list by Eclipse). As soon as that line was taken out, the class compiled.